# Google analytics Event : Track div

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am tracking click events with Google analytics and javascript by inserting something like :

```
<div id="mylinks">

<a href="http://mylink" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'link1', window.location.hostname, 'Advisers']);"></a>
<a href="http://mylink" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'link2', window.location.hostname, 'Advisers']);"></a>
<a href="http://mylink" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'link3', window.location.hostname, 'Advisers']);"></a>

</div>
```

I am looking for a way to track **how many time** the **div mylinks** has been clicked knowing that I have multiple click events in my web page

```
<div id="mylinks" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mydivlinks', window.location.hostname, 'Advisers']);">

<a href="http://mylink" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'link1', window.location.hostname, 'Advisers']);"></a>
<a href="http://mylink" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'link2', window.location.hostname, 'Advisers']);"></a>
<a href="http://mylink" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'link3', window.location.hostname, 'Advisers']);"></a>

</div>
```

If the visitor clicks on a link (inside the div), is it going to track the LINK EVENT **and** THE DIV EVENT ?

Comment: have you tried testing it?

Comment: @Dalmto no because, it takes time to get "events" in my report so I want to be sure this is going to work

Comment: You can see events instantly in real-time reports or as close to instant as is possible.  I would like to hear what happens I almost wonder if you will get a double hit.

Comment: btw welcome to stack:  I removed a few of your excessive tags its best to keep the tags to the point.  No need to add to many just keep to the ones that describe the problem.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you :)

Comment: Just chiming in with my own experiences here. At least using UA, you would get multiple events - one for the DIV click and one for the anchor click. I suspect you would likely see the same thing with the classic GA tracking.